# Conditioning by a random function

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, conditional-probability

Let $W_t$ denote the standard Wiener process (zero mean).

Let $B$ be a uniform binary random variable taking values $\pm 1$ independent of the stochastic process $\{W_t\}$.

We define
$$Y_t = B + W_t ,\quad 0\leq t\leq 1$$

Suppose I observe the sample path $Y_t,\ 0\leq t\leq 1$.

How do I calculate the conditional distribution of $B$ given the sample path $Y_t,\ 0\leq t\leq 1$?

Comment: It depends at which time you include $B$ in your filtration, as is with no further information I would assume it should be known at time $0$, then if $B$ is known at time $0$ $W_t$ is completely unambiguously determined If $Y_0=1$ then $W_t= Y_t-1$, else $W_t=Y_t$. If $B$ is known later on, then the equation of $Y_t$ is ambiguous and you should add the time when $B$ is revealed otherwise the process is not clearly measurable (or even adapted). You could even add a random time at which $B$ is known for example but you should add some specifications to your problem

Comment: @TheBridge, I am confused a little. I can explain a little: $B$ is a random variable not a stochastic process and we do not know the value of $B$. What I have observed is the sample path of the stochastic process ${Y_t}$ for the time period $[0,1]$. And I have to estimate $B$ from the sample path of ${Y_t}$. Can you please tell me what detail is missing?

Comment: Well if you can oberve the path o Y then it is either continuous in which case you know that $B= 0$ or discontinuous at the time where $\Delta Y_t=1$.